# How to push dynamic columns and row data to antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[image]

The below code is not accepting for an array of rows and columns

Here is antd example:

```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Edward King ${i}`,
    age: 32
    //  address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`
  });
}

Tried same logic in below: 
// columns :datacloumns1
// rows :rowdata

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < reportDataRows?.length; j++){
  data.push({
  datacloumns1[i]:rowdata[i] // here i am binding row to the exact column but this is not accepting
  });
}
}
```

Comment: You can't push an object property like that. Remove `for` loop with j with this: `data.datacloumn[i] = [...rowdata[i]]`

Comment: Thank you much for responding..  when remove loop and added this line  data.push(datacolumn[i]=[...rowdata[i]] but rowdata still not displaying row by row ..  const data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < reportDataRows?.length; i++) {
            data.push([datacloumns1[i]]=[rowdata[i]]);
        } this is how have changed my logic but row data is repeating 4 times and printing in single column

Comment: GroupId ,Name, abbrevation, Partners                                                                                     1              1             1                 1                                                                                            ABC         ABC        ABC             ABC                                                                                     A              A            A                  A                                                                                         AAA         AAA       AAA             AAA   repeating rows

Comment: GroupId ,Name, abbrevation, Partners .. are my columns  expected output                                                             1             ABC      A                  AAA

Comment: why don't you use ```useState``` hook to update the table?

Comment: Hi Jabal , Thanks for your response ... but the issue is with antd table columns and rows data binding not with update ..

Comment: Could you provide us with your current issue on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so that we can debug it on there?

Comment: Thank you i got the solution

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your suggestions.

Here is the solution: have changed my result to `title` and `dataIndex` format, so I realized that antd table accepts only the  `title` and `dataIndex` format.

```
let datacloumns = reportDataRows && Object.keys(reportDataRows[0])?.map((key) => (
    <span >{cloumns.push({
        title: key, dataIndex: key,
        //defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
        sorter: true
    })}
    </span>))

< Table 
  rowClassName = {(record, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? 'table-row-light' : 'table-row-dark'} 
  size = { 'default'} 
  columns = { cloumns } 
  bordered = { true} 
  sortDirections = { ['ascend', 'descend'] } 
  loading = { reportDataRows === undefined ? true : false} 
  pagination = {{ pageSize: 10 }} dataSource = { reportDataRows === undefined ? [] : reportDataRows} 
/>
```